# How do translations work in Craft 3?

Tags: craft3

I currently have a Craft 2 site deployment with a translations folder and a `en_gb.php` translations file.

I would be able to use expressions like this: `{{"visualization"|t}}`

However, this does not work in Craft 3. What is the new format for translation in Craft 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the changes made to static translations in Craft 3 in the Craft 3 upgrade docs here:

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#static-translation-files

In your case, `craft/translations/en_gb.php` would need to change to `craft/translations/en-GB/site.php`.

Comment: I'm confused by this answer because there is no longer a "craft" folder in Craft3 aside from whatever you might find inside the vendor folder. I'm not really supposed to put files manually inside the vendor folder, am I?

Comment: Just make a `translations` folder alongside the root of your project where `vendor` lives.

Comment: The link no longer works.